# Choose a different color theme for printing in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, color-scheme

I like to use the excellent [solarized color theme for Emacs](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized). I generally use the solorized-dark version for everyday use, which looks great on screen.

However, I regularly use org-mode and like to write the current agenda view to a PDF (`C-x C-w`). The resultant PDF uses the same color theme, which doesn't look that great when printed (some text is difficult to read etc.) or even when displayed in a PDF viewer.

Is there any way to get emacs to use a different color theme (i.e. a more high-contrast one) when exporting?

Comment: For the color theme (particularly for Org), you may be interested by my Leuven theme (see https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven-theme), which is high contrast on white background.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want (a particular theme), but you can use variable `org-agenda-exporter-settings` for control variables when exporting.

For instance, this ensures having high-contrast, as you want (but you lose pretty colors, so you might want to further refine):

```
(setq org-agenda-exporter-settings
      '((ps-print-color-p 'black-white)))
```